# Get Mail and Relies by Subject with Exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm using exchangelib library for my project.

I tried search from doc. But I want to list all replies to this mail.

```
filtered_items = a.inbox.filter(subject__contains='foo')
```

How can I get mail and replies? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most email threads in Exchange have a common `conversation_id` field. You could try filtering on that. Otherwise, there could be message `headers` with a common ID, and finally you could rely on a common pattern in the subject. Here's an example using `conversation_id`:

```py
filtered_item = a.inbox.get(subject__contains='foo')
replies = a.inbox.filter(conversation_id=filtered_item.conversation_id)
```